# Performance of std::vector<Test> vs std::vector<Test*>

Tags: performance, pointers, stl, vector, stdvector

In an std::vector of a non POD data type, is there a difference between a vector of objects and a vector of (smart) pointers to objects? I mean a difference in the implementation of these data structures by the compiler.

E.g.:

```
class Test {
   std::string s;
   Test *other;
};

std::vector<Test> vt;
std::vector<Test*> vpt;
```

Could be there no performance difference between vt and vpt?

In other words: when I define a `vector<Test>`, internally will the compiler create a `vector<Test*>` anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In other words: when I define a vector, internally will the compiler create a vector anyway?

No, this is not allowed by the C++ standard. The following code is legal C++:

```
vector<Test> vt;
Test t1; t1.s = "1"; t1.other = NULL;
Test t2; t2.s = "1"; t2.other = NULL;
vt.push_back(t1);
vt.push_back(t2);
Test* pt = &vt[0];
pt++;
Test q = *pt; // q now equal to Test(2)
```

In other words, a vector "decays" to an array (accessing it like a C array is legal), so the compiler effectively has to store the elements internally as an array, and may not just store pointers.

But beware that the array pointer is valid only as long as the vector is not reallocated (which normally only happens when the size grows beyond capacity).

Answer (score 2):

In general, whatever the type being stored in the vector is, instances of that may be copied.  This means that if you are storing a std::string, instances of std::string will be copied.

For example, when you push a Type into a vector, the Type instance is copied into a instance housed inside of the vector.  The copying of a pointer will be cheap, but, as Konrad Rudolph pointed out in the comments, this should not be the only thing you consider.

For simple objects like your `Test`, copying is going to be so fast that it will not matter.

Additionally, with C++11, moving allows avoiding creating an extra copy if one is not necessary.

So in short: A pointer will be copied faster, but copying is not the only thing that matters.  I would worry about maintainable, logical code first and performance when it becomes a problem (or the situation calls for it).

---

As for your question about an internal pointer vector, no, vectors are implemented as arrays that are periodically resized when necessary.  You can find GNU's libc++ implementation of vector online.

The answer gets a lot more complicated at a lower than C++ level.  Pointers will of course have to be involved since an entire program cannot fit into registers.  I don't know enough about that low of level to elaborate more though.

Comment: This makes it sound as if using pointers were faster. I claim that, at least for a lot of common usage patterns, the *opposite* is the case: using pointers is *slower* due to t he added indirection and overhead of memory management. C++11 move assignment makes this even more true but it holds even in C++03.

Comment: I edited my question. Maybe the last line clarifies what I am wandering about.

Comment: @Pietro Have updated my answer to address that and to hopefully be cleared.

Comment: Konrad Rudolph , can you please explain why pointer can be slower? if the list is list<Test> dosnt it require to create new instance of Test and copy the value when call to push_back?  Thank you